# Why no Reference Counting + Garbage Collection in C#?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, reference-counting

I come from a C++ background and I've been working with C# for about a year.  Like many others I'm flummoxed as to why deterministic resource management is not built-in to the language.  Instead of deterministic destructors we have the dispose pattern. [People start to wonder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/752344) whether spreading the IDisposable cancer through their code is worth the effort.

In my C++-biased brain it seems like using reference-counted smart pointers with deterministic destructors is a major step up from a garbage collector that requires you to implement IDisposable and call dispose to clean up your non-memory resources.  Admittedly, I'm not very smart...  so I'm asking this purely from a desire to better understand why things are the way they are.

What if C# were modified such that:

Objects are reference counted.  When an object's reference count goes to zero, a resource cleanup method is called deterministically on the object, then the object is marked for garbage collection.  Garbage collection occurs at some non-deterministic time in the future at which point memory is reclaimed.  In this scenario you don't have to implement IDisposable or remember to call Dispose.  You just implement the resource cleanup function if you have non-memory resources to release.

- Why is that a bad idea?
- Would that defeat the purpose of the garbage collector?
- Would it be feasible to implement such a thing?

EDIT:
From the comments so far, this is a bad idea because

1. GC is faster without reference counting
2. problem of dealing with cycles in the object graph

I think number one is valid, but number two is easy to deal with using weak references.

So does the speed optimization outweigh the cons that you:

1. may not free a non-memory resource in a timely manner
2. might free a non-memory resource too soon

If your resource cleanup mechanism is deterministic and built-in to the language you can eliminate those possibilities.

Comment: Apple just announced that Objective C in iOS 5 will support "Automatic Reference Counting".  All Objective C pointers are automatically reference counted and retain/released.  However, Objective C still supports dealloc which gives you a deterministic "destructor" where you can release non-memory resources and you don't have to mess with IDisposable.  They've specifically stated that they won't support a GC for Objective C.  Sounds like the right approach to me. Java and .NET got this wrong, IMO.

Comment: One thing that I'm worried about when it comes to GC is that event subscribers, even implementing weak event patterns, continues to receive notifications while waiting to be garbage collected. This makes mandatory the implementation of IDisposable in all event subscribers classes.

Comment: yep, and from the accepted answer: "We feel that it is very important to solve the cycle problem without forcing programmers to understand, track down and design around these complex data structure problems."

I was reminded of this today as I was forced to understand, track down and design around complex data structure AND object lifetime interactions in order to figure out why memory was not being released.  Someone forgot to dispose an object that unsubscribes from a global event handler in Dispose().  Reactive Extensions make everything disposable.

Comment: what do you mean "non-memory resource"?

Comment: A file handle, a mutex, a reference to native code. Any system resource allocated to your process that requires cleanup  other than memory.

Comment: Regarding reason #1(GC is faster without reference counting), that speed is relative. We have designed systems that handle millions of long-lived class instances in memory and found out that performance degrades greatly (building the GC reachable graph becomes a killer). In cases like this, the cost of reference counting would be dwarfed by the cost of reference tracking). We have resorted to a) migrating classes to structs, so that the container only needs to keep track of the backing array reference - and b) use of unmanaged memory. Your proposal would benefit cases like ours greatly.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Brad Abrams posted [an e-mail from Brian Harry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/archive/blogs/brada/resource-management) written during development of the .Net framework. It details many of the reasons reference counting was not used, even when one of the early priorities was to keep semantic equivalence with VB6, which uses reference counting. It looks into possibilities such as having some types ref counted and not others (`IRefCounted`!), or having specific instances ref counted, and why none of these solutions were deemed acceptable.

> Because [the issue of resource
> management and deterministic
> finalization] is such a
> sensitive topic I am going to try to
> be as precise and complete in my
> explanation as I can.  I apologize for
> the length of the mail.  The first 90%
> of this mail is trying to convince you
> that the problem really is hard.  In
> that last part, I'll talk about things
> we are trying to do but you need the
> first part to understand why we are
> looking at these options.
>
> ...
>
> We initially started with the
> assumption that **the solution would
> take the form of automatic ref
> counting** (so the programmer couldn't
> forget) plus some other stuff to
> detect and handle cycles
> automatically.  ...we **ultimately concluded that
> this was not going to work in the
> general case.**
>
> ...
>
> In summary:
>
> - We feel that it is very important to **solve the cycle problem**
>   without forcing programmers to
>   understand, track down and design
>   around these complex data structure
>   problems.
> - We want to make sure we have a high performance (both speed and
>   working set) system and our analysis
>   shows that using **reference counting
>   for every single object in the system
>   will not allow us to achieve this
>   goal**.
> - For a variety of reasons, including composition and casting
>   issues, there is **no simple transparent
>   solution to having just those objects
>   that need it be ref counted**.
> - We chose not to select a solution that provides **deterministic
>   finalization for a single
>   language/context because it inhibits
>   interop** with other languages and
>   causes bifurcation of class libraries
>   by creating language specific
>   versions.

Comment: Definitely read the complete mail - it explains the reasoning behind the decision in great detail.

Comment: Microsoft have broken all their blog links. I think this is the new home for the [Resource management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/archive/blogs/brada/resource-management) article linked in this reply. It took me a while to find.

Answer (score 31):

The garbage collector does not require you to write a Dispose method for **every** class/type that you define. You only define one when you need to explicitly do something to cleanup ; when you have explicitly allocated native resources. Most of the time, the GC just reclaims memory even if you only do something like new() up an object.

The GC does reference counting - however it does it in a different way by finding which objects are 'reachable' (`Ref Count > 0`) **every time it does a collection**... it just doesn't do it in a integer counter way. . Unreachable objects are collected (`Ref Count = 0`). This way the runtime doesn't have to do housekeeping/updating tables everytime an object is assigned or released... should be faster.

The only major difference between C++ (deterministic) and C# (non-deterministic) is when the object would be cleaned up. You can't predict the exact moment an object would be collected in C#.

*Umpteenth plug: I'd recommend reading Jeffrey Richter's standup chapter on the GC in [CLR via C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735621632) in case you're really interested in how the GC works.*

Comment: So, eschew RAII because reference counting is slower and you don't have to deal with Dispose on every class. Seems like a poor tradeoff to me.

Comment: Didn't understand your comment here... I just explained that implementing Dispose is not mandatory for every C# type/class. GC works perfectly even if none of your classes implemented Dispose.

Comment: I'm not sure my question was fully understood.  Many many classes in the framework implmeent IDisposable.  You must call dispose on those classes. It would be nice if RAII were possible to help with that.  Anyway, it seems that most people agree with your reasoning.

Comment: Actually, you don't _have_ to call dispose on every implementer of IDisposable.  If the object is well-written/has a finalizer, the resources will still get collected.  IDisposable provides a means for deterministic release if you _need_ it to be deterministic.  If you only grab a particular OS resource on an infrequent basis, the non-deterministic finalization may well be good enough.  Think of it as extending the classic C++ "opt-in" notion to resource management.

Comment: How can you be sure if the object is well-written if you didn't write it yourself?

Comment: @Skrymsli assume it is well-written and move on. most of the time it will be. If it's not, *and* it causes a problem, it's trivial to open the code in a tool like Reflector and find out exactly what needs to be done with regards to disposal.

Comment: @Skrymsli:  Rex M is right.  And it's safe to assume that everything in the framework (which is what you were referring to in the comment before mine) is well-written.

Answer (score 23):

Reference counting was tried in C#. I believe, the folks that released Rotor (a reference implementation of CLR for which the source was made available) did reference counting-based GC just to see how it would compare to the generational one. The result was surprising -- the "stock" GC was so much faster, it was not even funny. I don't remember exactly where I heard this, I think it was one of the Hanselmuntes podcasts. If you want to see C++ get basically crushed in performance comparison with C# -- google Raymond Chen's chinese dictionary app. He did a C++ version, and then Rico Mariani did a C# one. I think it took Raymond 6 iterations to finally beat the C# version, but by that time he had to drop all the nice object orientednes of C++, and get down to the win32 API level. The entire thing turned into a performance hack. C# program, at the same time, was optimized only once, and in the end still looked like a decent OO project

Comment: Reference counting is known to be slower overall than tracing GCs. However, it has the benefit of lower maximum pause times, and memory will often be released as soon as possible.

Comment: From memory I don't think the Rotor runtime was very optimised so I don't think it's a very good data point. +1 for the dictionary app reference that was interesting. Here is the link for reference: http://blogs.msdn.com/ricom/archive/2005/05/10/416151.aspx

Comment: I feel the need to point out a non-trivial amount of the effort Mr. Chen had to go to was due to the fact that the standard C++ library - or maybe just most current implementations - is crap for performance (being designed for a "sufficiently intelligent optimizer") - it would be perfectly possible to write an as efficient program in OO style.

Comment: @Simon:  Be that as it may, the fact remains that with currently-available tools, it was much easier, faster, and less error-prone to write c# code that performed well than it was to write c++ code that performed well.

Comment: @Unknown: "[Reference counting] has the benefit of lower maximum pause times, and memory will often be released as soon as possible". On the contrary, reference counting introduces unbounded pause times as the entire heap can be collected in an avalanche of destructors and reference counting defers collection until the end of scope which can be (and often is) later than the end of liveness.

Comment: It depends on the reference counting algorithm. If you use it at each assignment it will kill you because it's not only a write access but also full blown CAS with write barrier to make the ref counting MT safe. But if you use a Cocoa style memory policy i doubt that a tracing GC is faster.

Comment: @Lothar: Can you elaborate on "cocoa style memory policy"? Obviously there's a huge amount of evidence in decades of GC research papers that concludes that tracing GC is faster...

Comment: @JonHarrop in modern referencing counting algorithms there is no need to process all of the increment/decrements at once. Instead they are placed onto a queue and processed periodically. It allows for very small pause times:
http://researcher.watson.ibm.com/researcher/files/us-bacon/Bacon03Pure.pdf

Comment: @LukeQuinane: So when you wrote "faster" you meant latency rather than throughput?

Comment: Interesting example. So, I guess the easy understanding is, if I have 10000 pointers in a vector and copy those pointers to 1000 new vectors, basically each copy, I have to keep increasing the pointer's count. That is like 10000 * 1000 count increments in total. But, on C#, it just ignores it and counts it at the very end. And it probably stops counting after 1 because there is no need to know 1000 vectors stores this one pointer. Another big thing is probably memory fragmentation if you release it too soon. In short, on C#, spam new, on C++, don't spam new shared_ptr.

Answer (score 15):

There is a difference between C++ style smart pointer reference counting and reference counting garbage collection. I've also talked about the differences on [my blog](http://lukequinane.blogspot.com/2009/04/smart-pointers-managed-automatic-memory.html) but here is a quick summary:

#### C++ Style Reference Counting:

- **Unbounded cost on decrement:** if the root of a large data structure is decremented to zero there is an unbounded cost to free all the data.
- **Manual cycle collection:** to prevent cyclic data structures from leaking memory the programmer must manually break any potential structures by replacing part of the cycle with a weak smart pointer. This is another source of potential defects.

#### Reference Counting Garbage Collection

- **Deferred RC:** Changes to an object reference count are ignored for stack and register references. Instead when a GC is triggered these objects are retained by collecting a root set.
  Changes to the reference count can be deferred and processed in batches. This results in [higher throughput](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=390011.808261).
- **Coalescing:** using a write barrier it is possible to [coalesce](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1111596.1111597) changes to the reference count. This makes it possible to ignore most changes to an objects reference count improving RC performance for frequently mutated references.
- **Cycle Detection:** for a complete GC implementation a cycle detector must also be used. However it is possible to perform cycle detection in incremental fashion, which in turn means bounded GC time.

Basically it is possible to implement a high performance RC based garbage collector for runtimes such as Java's JVM and the .net CLR runtime.

I think tracing collectors are partly in use for historical reasons: many of the recent improvements in reference counting came after both the JVM and .net runtime were released. Research work also takes time to transition into production projects.

### Deterministic Resource Disposal

This is pretty much a separate issue. The .net runtime makes this possible using the IDisposable interface, example below. I also like [Gishu's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1695/gishu) answer.

---

[@Skrymsli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/105568/skrymsli), this is the purpose of the "[using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx)" keyword. E.g.:

```
public abstract class BaseCriticalResource : IDiposable {
    ~ BaseCriticalResource () {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    public void Dispose() {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this); // No need to call finalizer now
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing) { }
}
```

Then to add a class with a critical resource:

```
public class ComFileCritical : BaseCriticalResource {

    private IntPtr nativeResource;

    protected override Dispose(bool disposing) {
        // free native resources if there are any.
        if (nativeResource != IntPtr.Zero) {
            ComCallToFreeUnmangedPointer(nativeResource);
            nativeResource = IntPtr.Zero;
        }
    }
}
```

Then to use it is as simple as:

```
using (ComFileCritical fileResource = new ComFileCritical()) {
    // Some actions on fileResource
}

// fileResource's critical resources freed at this point
```

See also [implementing IDisposable correctly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244737(VS.80).aspx).

Comment: Interesting blog post...  I'm less concerned about freeing the memory than freeing non-memory resources which are potentially time-critical. (Think of a handle to a COM object that holds a file lock.  You want that lock to be released when you are done with it, not when the GC runs a finalizer at some future time.)  I think there has to be some combination of GC and smart pointers that provides the best of both worlds where you get exceptional memory management and yet critical resources can be deterministically freed without undue burden on the programmer.

Comment: When I ask about this is isn't because I don't know about using or the right way to dispose of resources.  I just think its WRONG that we have to do it at all! It usually works out as you described above.  What if you need to hold on to that resource?  You need to implement IDisposable now. Also, the programmer has to know to wrap the stuff in the using construct. (I know, use FXCop!) That's just syntactic sugar for calling free, release, dispose.  The compiler should *know* to do it.  This is the major bonus of the C++ RAII idiom.  Sorry, I'm probably just dumb.

Comment: @Skrymsli you are not alone in your "dumbness", I also suggested it several years ago: http://www.dotnet247.com/247reference/msgs/26/131667.aspx

Comment: @Skrymsli: FWIW, `using` is a C# thing and other languages like F# have solutions that look more like RAII in C++.

Comment: "it is possible to implement a high performance RC based garbage collector for runtimes such as Java's JVM and the .net CLR runtime". Production GCs using tracing instead of RC precisely because that is not true.

Comment: @JonHarrop you should check out modern reference counting implementations, e.g [Ulterior Reference Counting](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~mckinley/papers/urc-oopsla-2003.pdf). They can achieve higher throughput than naive mark-sweep and still keep pause times low.

Comment: @Luke "you should check out modern reference counting implementations, e.g Ulterior Reference Counting". That's 10 years old and it only gets better performance by deferring decrements which introduces floating garbage, i.e. by sacrificing one of the core benefits of naive reference counting. Where are these "high-performance RC-based garbage collectors" for the JVM and .NET? The Garbage Collection Handbook (2012) does not allude to their existence... http://gchandbook.org/

Comment: @JonHarrop here is a more up to date paper: [Down for the Count?](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~steveb/downloads/pdf/rc-ismm-2012.pdf). I should also mentioned that Steve taught me at ANU, so I'm a bit biased in this area :) As with most things there are obviously trade offs to make when choosing a GC, but it seems like RC works well in some cases and I'm not sure why there aren't more GC algorithms available in modern VMs. Last I heard Apache Harmony was going to look at adding in MMTk to allow some more GC algorithms to be used.

Comment: @LukeQuinane They claim that reference counting "can reclaim objects as soon as they are no longer referenced" but then admit that it would be "extremely costly" and state that they "are not aware of any high performance system that relies on reference counting". Also, it is wrong to pretend that reference counting is more incremental than tracing collection. Naive reference counting causes avalanches but can be made incrementatl. Naive mark-sweep is a batch operation but Dijkstra-style tri-color marking can make it just as incremental.

Comment: Also, am I correct in assuming that they benchmarked only serial programs on a machine with only two cores? If so, that is quite disingenious given that quadcores are more common and most programs where performance is relevant are parallel.

Comment: And I'd like to see experimental measurements to justify their claims about "promptness of recovery". In my experience, scope based reference counting produces more floating garbage than generational mark sweep and is many times slower. Deferral will increase performance but also the amount of floating garbage. FWIW, the only production system I use that is based upon reference counting is Mathematica and it is awful (very slow with long pauses).

Answer (score 8):

> I come from a C++ background and I've been working with C# for about a year. Like many others I'm flummoxed as to why deterministic resource management is not built-in to the language.

The `using` construct provides "deterministic" resource management and is built into the C# language. Note that by "deterministic" I mean `Dispose` is guaranteed to have been called before the code after the `using` block starts executing. Note also that this is not what the word "deterministic" means but everyone seems to abuse it in this context in that way, which sucks.

> In my C++-biased brain it seems like using reference-counted smart pointers with deterministic destructors is a major step up from a garbage collector that requires you to implement IDisposable and call dispose to clean up your non-memory resources.

The garbage collector does not require you to implement `IDisposable`. Indeed, the GC is completely oblivious to it.

> Admittedly, I'm not very smart... so I'm asking this purely from a desire to better understand why things are the way they are.

Tracing garbage collection is a fast and reliable way to emulate an infinite memory machine, freeing the programmer from the burden of manual memory management. This eliminated several classes of bugs (dangling pointers, free too soon, double free, forgot to free).

> What if C# were modified such that:
>
> Objects are reference counted. When an object's reference count goes to zero, a resource cleanup method is called deterministically on the object,

Consider an object shared between two threads. The threads race to decrement the reference count to zero. One thread will win the race and the other will be responsible for cleanup. That is non-deterministic. The belief that reference counting is inherently deterministic is a myth.

Another common myth is that reference counting frees objects at the earliest possible point in the program. It doesn't. Decrements are always deferred, usually to the end of scope. This keeps objects alive for longer than necessary leaving what is called "floating garbage" lying around. Note that, in particular, some tracing garbage collectors can and do recycle objects earlier than scope-based reference counting implementations.

> then the object is marked for garbage collection. Garbage collection occurs at some non-deterministic time in the future at which point memory is reclaimed. In this scenario you don't have to implement IDisposable or remember to call Dispose.

You don't have to implement `IDisposable` for garbage collected objects anyway, so that is a non-benefit.

> You just implement the resource cleanup function if you have non-memory resources to release.
>
> Why is that a bad idea?

Naive reference counting is very slow and leaks cycles. For example, [Boost's `shared_ptr` in C++ is up to 10x slower than OCaml's tracing GC](http://flyingfrogblog.blogspot.co.uk/2011/01/boosts-sharedptr-up-to-10-slower-than.html). Even naive scope-based reference counting is non-deterministic in the presence of multithreaded programs (which is almost all modern programs).

> Would that defeat the purpose of the garbage collector?

Not at all, no. In fact it is a bad idea that was invented in the 1960s and subjected to intense academic study for the next 54 years concluding that reference counting sucks in the general case.

> Would it be feasible to implement such a thing?

Absolutely. Early prototype .NET and JVM used reference counting. They also found it sucked and dropped it in favor of tracing GC.

> EDIT: From the comments so far, this is a bad idea because
>
> GC is faster without reference counting

Yes. Note that you can make reference counting much faster by deferring counter increments and decrements but that sacrifices the determinism that you crave so very much and it is still slower than tracing GC with today's heap sizes. However, reference counting is asymptotically faster so at some point in the future when heaps get really big maybe we will start using RC in production automated memory management solutions.

> problem of dealing with cycles in the object graph

Trial deletion is an algorithm specifically designed to detect and collect cycles in reference counted systems. However, it is slow and non-deterministic.

> I think number one is valid, but number two is easy to deal with using weak references.

Calling weak references "easy" is a triumph of hope over reality. They are a nightmare. Not only are they unpredictable and difficult to architect but they pollute APIs.

> So does the speed optimization outweigh the cons that you:
>
> may not free a non-memory resource in a timely manner

Doesn't `using` free non-memory resource in a timely manner?

> might free a non-memory resource too soon
>   If your resource cleanup mechanism is deterministic and built-in to the language you can eliminate those possibilities.

The `using` construct is deterministic and built into the language.

I think the question you really want to ask is why doesn't `IDisposable` use reference counting. My response is anecdotal: I've been using garbage collected languages for 18 years and I have never needed to resort to reference counting. Consequently, I much prefer simpler APIs that aren't polluted with incidental complexity like weak references.

Comment: I would have liked to have seen a standard pattern to handle the scenario where multiple independent references exist to an immutable object that holds resources (e.g. a bitmap or other such GDI object that's never going to be modified), and there's no telling which one will be the last to need it.  Something like reference-counting would have been good there, if the count were incremented not on every reference copy, but on each each call to `AddOwner`, and were decremented when they are `Dispose`d.  Thus, a method which could either satisfy a request for a bitmap by creating a new one...

Comment: ...in which it would have no further interest, or by returning a reference to a shared one that nobody would ever modify, could either return a new bitmap on which `AddOwner` had not been called, or could call `AddOwner` on a shared bitmap and return a reference to that.  The recipient could then call `Dispose` on the shared bitmap in any case, and doing so would dispose the bitmap if and only if that recipient happened to be the last entity that had needed it to stay alive.

Comment: @supercat: I wonder if reference counting in an environment that uses tracing garbage collection would work well. For objects that are never referred to from the heap that might work well.

Comment: I think the key is to keep track of *references that include an ownership interest*.  The number of those doesn't change nearly as often as the number of references that *exist*.  Further, I would see tracing garbage collection as being a very useful adjunct to reference counting--not so much as a backstop for when things don't get freed, but the reverse: to ensure that if a resource gets freed out from under code that's trying to use it, the code can find out about it rather than merely wandering into Undefined Behaviorland.

Answer (score 5):

I know something about garbage collection. Here is a short summary because a full explanation is beyond the bounds of this question.

.NET uses a copying and compacting generational garbage collector. This is more advanced than reference counting and has the benefit of being able to collect objects that refer to themselves either directly, or through a chain.

Reference counting will not collect cycles. Reference counting also has a lower throughput (slower overall) but with the benefit of faster pauses (maximal pauses are smaller) than a tracing collector.

Comment: This point could be argued but it seems easier to avoid a cycle in a reference counted system using weak references than it is to avoid resource leaks or delayed release with IDisposable.

Comment: @Skrymsli actually that point cannot be argued. Sometimes you don't know when you'll create a reference cycle.

Comment: Only naïve reference counting implementations will not collect cycles. High performance reference counting is also possible for runtimes such as .net: http://cs.anu.edu.au/~Steve.Blackburn/pubs/papers/urc-oopsla-2003.pdf

Comment: @Luke, that is incorrect. The paper you cite is a misnomer. Their "ulterior reference counting" implements tracing, which by standard definitions, is not a pure reference counting GC.

Comment: You are correct, it is a hybrid MS/RC collector, however it only uses MS for the nusery. I.e. it is a mostly reference counting garbage collector. Also many RC implementations use MS to collect cycles.

Comment: @LukeQuinane: "mostly reference counting garbage collector". What proportion of all objects allocated survive long enough to get to be reference counted? Much less than 50%, right? So how is that "mostly" RC?

Comment: @JonHarrop that's going to varying a lot depending on the application running. It also depends on how long those older generation objects live for (sometimes many hundreds of GCs). You can check out how some "real world" programs allocate their objects (unfortunately no functional language benchmark, which would have been interesting): http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~steveb/dacapobench.org/dacapo-graphs/index.html

In GC there is always a trade off one way or another.

Answer (score 4):

There's a lot of issues in play here. First of all you need to distinguish between freeing managed memory and clean-up of other resources. The former can be really fast whereas the later may be very slow. In .NET the two are separated, which allows for faster clean-up of managed memory. This also implies, that you should only implement Dispose/Finalizer when you have something beyond managed memory to clean up.

The .NET employs a mark and sweep technique where it traverses the heap looking for roots to objects. Rooted instances survive the garbage collection. Everything else can be cleaned by just reclaiming the memory. The GC has to compact memory every now and then, but apart from that reclaiming memory is a simple pointer operation even when reclaiming multiple instances. Compare this with multiple calls to destructors in C++.

Comment: +1 for noting the two separate aspects. People tend to think Dispose() is for freeing up memory...

Comment: It has been 10 years since I first asked this question and I'm now used to the GC. In re-reading these comments today, it is reiterated that I don't need IDisposable for the GC to work. I knew that when I asked this question. It is beside the point. The complaint is about having to call dispose at all. I still wish for the good old days when finding memory leaks was as simple as running valgrind. In C# there are a bunch of profilers which I find hard to use. The typical source of memory leaks in C# today are event subscriptions that are unsubscribed in Dispose, but Dispose isn't called.

Answer (score 1):

The object implemeting IDisposable must also implement a finalizer called by the GC when the user doesn't explicit call Dispose - see [IDisposable.Dispose at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose.aspx).

The whole point of IDisposable is that the GC is running at some non-deterministic time and you implement IDisposable because you hold a valuable resource and wants to free it at a deterministic time.

So your proposal would change nothing in terms of IDisposable.

Edit:

Sorry. Didn't read your proposal correctly. :-(

Wikipedia has a simple explanation of the [shortcomings of References counted GC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting#Advantages_and_disadvantages)

Comment: FWIW, the content on Wikipedia about garbage collection and reference counting is mostly wrong including the section you've cited.

Answer (score 1):

**Reference count**

The costs of using reference counts are twofold: First, every object requires the special reference count field. Typically, this means an extra word of storage must be allocated in each object. Second, every time one reference is assigned to another, the reference counts must be adjusted. This increases significantly the time taken by assignment statements.

**Garbage Collection in .NET**

C# does not use reference counting of the objects. Instead it maintains a graph of the object references from the stack and navigates from the root to cover up all the referenced objects. All the referenced objects in the graph are compacted in the heap to that a contiguous memory is available for future objects. Memory for all the unreferenced objects who do not need to be finalized is reclaimed. Those that are unreferenced but have finalizers to be executed on them are moved to a separate queue called the f-reachable queue where the garbage collector calls their finalizers in the background.

In addition to the above GC uses the concept of generations for a more efficient garbage collection. It is based on the following concepts
1. It is faster to compact the memory for a portion of the managed heap than for the entire managed heap
2. Newer objects will have shorter lifetimes and older objects will have longer lifetimes
3. Newer objects tend to be related to each other and accessed by the application around the same time

The managed heap is divided into three generations: 0, 1, and 2. The new objects are stored in gen 0. Objects that are not reclaimed by a cycle of GC are promoted to the next gen. So if newer objects which are in gen 0 survive GC cycle 1, then they are promoted to gen 1. Those among these that survive GC cycle 2 are promoted to gen 2.  Because the garbage collector supports only three generations, objects in generation 2 that survive a collection remain in generation 2 until they are determined to be unreachable in a future collection.

The garbage collector performs a collection when generation 0 is full and memory for new object needs to be allocated. If a collection of generation 0 does not reclaim enough memory, the garbage collector can perform a collection of generation 1, then generation 0. If this does not reclaim enough memory, the garbage collector can perform a collection of generations 2, 1, and 0.

Thus GC is more efficient than reference count.

Comment: Technically, it's a graph, not a tree, and the GC doesn't "maintain" it, it simply walks the references inside objects. Also, I'm not sure what you mean by "removal by the [GC] in the background" - do you mean the sweep phase? I think that immediately follows.

Comment: Thanks Simon. Edited the response as per your suggestion. I am not sure what the sweep phase is, what i meant was the objects out of scope who need finalization are processed separately by the GC in the background after the heap is compacted.

Comment: -1 for the unsupported statement "Thus GC is more efficient than reference count."

Answer (score 1):

Deterministic non-memory resource management is part of the language, however it is not done with destructors.

Your opinion is common among people coming from a C++ background, attempting to use the [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAII) design pattern. In C++ the only way you can guarrantee that some code will run in the end of a scope, even if an exeption is thrown, is to allocate an object on the stack and put the clean-up code in the destructor.

In other languages (C#, Java, Python, Ruby, Erlang, ...) you can use try-finally (or try-catch-finally) instead to ensure that the clean-up code will always run.

```
// Initialize some resource.
try {
    // Use the resource.
}
finally {
    // Clean-up.
    // This code will always run, whether there was an exception or not.
}
```

I C#, you can also use the [using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) construct:

```
using (Foo foo = new Foo()) {
    // Do something with foo.
}
// foo.Dispose() will be called afterwards, even if there
// was an exception.
```

Thus, for a C++-programmer, it might help to think about "running clean-up code" and "freeing memory" as two separate things. Put your clean-up code in a finally block and leave to the GC to take care of the memory.